# Why does Magento 2 does not support store based price?

Tags: magento2.2.6

I need the price of product store wise, but by default Magento 2 not support that.

Can anyone suggest me without extension solution, rather code based solution?

Comment: By default can able to set different prices for different store views in Magento

Comment: I don't think so. As much I know there are two scopes, one is website wise and another is global wise.

Comment: You mean price attribute ?

Comment: both price attribute and Store->Configuration->Catalog->Price->Catalog Price Scope

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the prices are not supported at store view level is because it's not normal to do so.
A store view is basically a "language" of a website.
It is not normal to have a price in English language and a price in German language for example.
Magento does support different prices per website. And if you need it on store view level you can just create your 2 store views as children of 2 different websites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 

But one thing can you explain, please. 

Is there any way to change the price of two website's two store view without changing the URL.

Comment: it depends on how you have the urls setup. If you have different urls setup for the 2 store views, then it should not be a problem to move them under separate websites. I don't think you need any additional work. But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Magento only supports global and website-level pricing because that's the limit they've put on their database schema. My guess is that featuring store-level prices significantly increases the cost of performance and complexity (indexing, speed, etc.). It's just not worth it from their point of view. You can use currency-converted store-level pricing (correct me if I'm wrong - M1 allowed it).

Store-level pricing is certainly possible, however. I've done it, and there are different ways to implement it, but it's not trivial. One word of advice, though. Avoid adding `store_id` to price tables. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Actually, there is an extension
https://bsscommerce.com/magento-multiple-store-view-pricing-for-magento-2.html
does this can be used or wise decision.

Answer (score 0):

To set different prices for different store views (**Both store views doesn't belongs to same website**0

- Goto Admin panel -> Catalog -> Products
- Edit any product
- Select store view at top left
- Set price for that store view and click save
- Clean cache and see that product in both stores on frontend

I hope this will help you.

Comment: You cannot set price on storeview scope, its either global or website based.

Comment: The above steps working for me

Comment: This was never possible in Magento. Please verify. Set default price. Go to storeview A, set price. Got to storeview B, set another price. Switch back to storeview A and you'll see the price you've entered last in storeview B.

Comment: Did you checked the above scenario ?

Comment: I have tested this in Magento EE 2.2.5

Comment: Yes, i've tested it (CE). Are you sure your storeview A & B belongs to same website?

Comment: @sv3n Am tested in enterprise edition, But my storeview A & B doesn't belongs to same website.

Comment: This is the problem :) If they belong to same website, I'm pretty sure it will not work.